# importing sql while restarting apache

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have a process of importing large db to mysql is going on via command tool.Now if I restart apache then will it effect importing the db to mysql process?

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: is it entirely command line mysql or is it going thru the webserver like php ?

Comment: It's entirely command line mysql...but it is using xampp>mysql>bin>mysql -u.....

Comment: from what i understand apache is completely unrelated to anything you are doing with the import

Comment: Right.I have restarted apache and it didn't effect the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP to communicate with MySQL then it's possible restarting Apache will interfere.  If you run `apachectl graceful` it will wait for all currently open connections to close before it restarts, a pretty nifty feature.

If you're connecting to MySQL via the command line then no restarting Apache will have no affect.

Comment: Thanks Chris.I was connecting to mysql via the command line.